# masonry js error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded'

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

When I try to use masonry js I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded'

I'm loading this scripts:

.jquery 1.10.2
.twitter bootstrap 2.3.2
.masonry 3.0.3

the scripts are loaded in that order and they load ok, I've checked.

I also tried removing the bootstrap js, but the error persisted.

the javascript that initializes masonry:

```
$(function(){
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.masonryImage'
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
    $(function(){
var $container = $('#container');


  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.masonryImage'
  });

});
```

because imgloaded script file is not attachted yo ur html file if you want to use that file download it from [here](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

Comment: shouldn't it come with jquery?

Comment: no its not function written in jquery files you have to download it separately the link is given

Comment: that solved the error. the problem is that the images are loaded via ajax dinamicly to a div and it isn't working that way. tried using imagesLoaded.js, but that gave me a new error. I'm still sorting it.

Comment: if ur loading images via ajax than reload masonry function in ajax success